# Code Coverage Tools and TDD

Tags: c#, tdd, code-coverage

I've recently been evaluating DotCover by JetBrains and it's led me to a interesting question.

When following TDD:

- I'll write a test against my desired ideal interface.
- Red
- Create the simplest implementation to pass the test.
- Green
- Run DotCover, which shows 100%.
- I'll then remove duplication/refactor.

If during the process of the refactoring I move some functionality into its own class (say for the sake of adhering to DRY or SRP), and then rerun DotCover, the coverage % will then drop as I'm no longer directly testing the new class.

This seems a bit strange to me as I'm following the tenets of TDD to the absolute letter. If I modify or comment out any line in the code, a test WILL break, yet it is reported as uncovered.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you move that logic to the new class, the new class should already be covered as the code you took it from is now invoking it.  I'm not familiar with DotCover, but I've used the Visual Studio one, and it bases its coverage percentage on solely whether the code executed, not how the unit test is written.

Comment: Eh? Why the down vote? The code in question is being executed by the test but shown as not covered. I'll try a different test tool.

Comment: I wouldn't fixate on code coverage if you are TDD'ing. I only look at coverage after I have finished a feature. Are you runnign all the tests under coverage as running just a single test may give odd results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotCover may want your units to be tested as units, thus the penalty for indirect testing.  And there's some merit to the argument that only the system under test should be considered in testing; when you extract a class but test it through the caller, you're really testing the caller and should (arguably) mock the new class - and have true unit tests for the new class, which test it as an independent unit.

Comment: This was my concern. I can understand the merits of testing units as units that are completely decoupled from each other if those distinct units are likely to be used by a different consumer than they currently are. If, however, those units are marked as internal and all code is exercised by the current tests, then I think the extra tests would just be maintenance burden. I suppose changing the modifier to public wouldn't break any tests though, and it would expose them for other consumers. Do you have any thoughts on the merits or disadvantages of either approach?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know .net well enough to have a good answer on this.  A class which is truly only useful to another class should probably be internal and private to that other class, and I wouldn't want to have to make it public just for testing.

Comment: @CarlManaster I agree with you on this one and it also depends on how you define a unit, to me a unit is one or more classes. Some of my colleagues disagree and would have every class tested on its own which I think is wasteful and silly and leads to way more mocking/stubbing then would normally be required.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this opens the argument of the definition of Unit Test vs Integration Tests.

You can use filters to exclude areas from the code coverage:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/filtering-with-dotcover/

Hope this helps.